# Matplotlib resizing pie graph when adding a picture

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm doing a pie graphic which is perfectly ruound, I then add a white circle in the middle so it looks like doghnut.

Finally I go an add an image in the middle of the graphic, from an example I found, which resizes the perfect circle to an elipse.

Pics:

[image: Perfect Circle]

[image]

Code:

```
> labels = df.index.values 
>sizes = (1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1,1)
> 
> DonutA = plt.pie(sizes, colors=df.ColorCond.map({True :'g', False :
> 'r'}), shadow=False, 
>                  wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1 , 'edgecolor' : 'lightgrey'}, radius=1)
> 
> #draw a circle at the center of pie to make it look like a donut centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.75,color='white',
> fc='white',linewidth=1) fig = plt.gcf()
> fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle) im =
> plt.imread(get_sample_data('C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\Sanmatech\\A2.png'))
> newax = fig.add_axes([0.33,0.36,0.37,0.30], anchor='SE', zorder=1)
> newax.imshow(im,  extent=(30, 50, 30, 50)) plt.axis('equal')
> newax.axis('off')
> 
> # Set aspect ratio to be equal so that pie is drawn as a circle.
> 
> plt.show()
```

Really struggline a little bit with this one, I have clear its the line:

```
 >newax = fig.add_axes([0.33,0.36,0.37,0.30], anchor='SE', zorder=1)
```

but have been playing for a few days without any luck:

Comment: Please just don't use pie charts. Especially to portray something with lots of categories/variables. Also, you might be leaning towards [chart junk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chartjunk) with this approach.

Comment: Please do use pie charts if you think that makes sense. We are not in the position to judge on that @Grr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the aspect with `plt.axis('equal')` to the axes in which the pie resides. This is easily being done by placing this line just before or after the pie creation.

```
plt.axis('equal')
DonutA = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=False, 
                 wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1 , 'edgecolor' : 'lightgrey'}, radius=1)
```

Note that in order to place a letter `A` into the plot you don't need an image.

Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

sizes = (1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1, 1, 1, 1,1,1)
colors = np.random.choice(["r", "g"], size=len(sizes))

plt.axis('equal')
DonutA = plt.pie(sizes, colors=colors, shadow=False, 
                 wedgeprops = { 'linewidth' : 1 , 'edgecolor' : 'lightgrey'}, radius=1)

#draw a circle at the center of pie to make it look like a donut 
centre_circle = plt.Circle((0,0),0.75,color='white', fc='white',linewidth=1) 
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.gca().add_artist(centre_circle) 

import matplotlib.patheffects as path_effects
text = plt.gca().text(0.0, 0.0, 'A', color='white', ha='center', va='center', size=100)
text.set_path_effects([path_effects.Stroke(linewidth=3, foreground='black'),
                       path_effects.Normal()])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you man! I defintely need to look a little more into matlplotlib and how it works, how did you learn by yourself? If there is any documentation you could share I'd be so thankfull!

Comment: For me personally, I did learning by doing. The matplotlib documentation is in itself very good and useful and there are some tutorials on the matplotlib page as well. Plus, there is the example gallery showing a good bunch of use cases. As far as I can tell there is also a lot of literature out about matplotlib and tutorial videos on youtube. Finally, since matplotlib is already quite mature, a lot of questions on SO are available.